# Plot graphs with ListPointPlot3D and different colours and size of points

Tags: color, visualization

Hello I am New in Mathematica.
I have a set of points and I want to visualize in Wolfram Mathematica.

I want to see big blue points and small green points in one picture.

Big Blue points

```
{{0.35, 5.9709, -0.494276}, 
 {0.25, 6.4709, -0.794276},
 {0.3, 6.2709, -0.564276}, 
 {0.3, 5.6709, -0.594276}}
```

Little Green points

```
{{0.3, -3.41212, -1.20591}, 
 {0.4, -3.21543, -1.12591}, 
 {0.4, -3.61472, -1.33312}}
```

I wrote the code, but it doesn't work

```
gg4 = ListPointPlot3D[{{0.35, 5.9709, -0.494276}, {0.25, 
    6.4709, -0.794276}, {0.3, 6.2709, -0.564276}, {0.3, 
    5.6709, -0.594276}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.04]}]
gg2 = ListPointPlot3D[{{0.3, -3.41212, -1.20591}, {0.4, -3.21543, \
-1.12591}, {0.4, -3.61472, -1.33312}},
  PlotStyle -> {Green, PointSize[0.01]}]
Show[gg4, gg2]
```

I see 2 problems:

1. The function `Show` , shows date only from `gg4`
2. The `PointSize` function doesn't work. It is working, when I write `PlotStyle -> { PointSize[0.01], Green}` , but the colour function is not working in this case.

Comment: `gg4 = ListPointPlot3D[{{0.35, 5.9709, -0.494276}, {0.25, 6.4709, -0.794276}, {0.3, 6.2709, -0.564276}, {0.3, 5.6709, -0.594276}}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.05]]];
gg2 = ListPointPlot3D[{{0.3, -3.41212, -1.20591}, {0.4, -3.21543, -1.12591}, {0.4, -3.61472, -1.33312}},PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, PointSize[0.05]]];
Show[gg4, gg2, PlotRange -> All]` gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IPc6a.png)

Comment: cross posted here http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/276618?p_p_auth=d6m9oI1v

Answer (score 3):

```
lst1 = {{0.35, 5.9709, -0.494276}, {0.25, 6.4709, -0.794276},   
        {0.3,  6.2709, -0.564276}, {0.3, 5.6709, -0.594276}};
lst2 = {{0.3, -3.41212, -1.20591}, {0.4, -3.21543, -1.12591}, {0.4, -3.61472, -1.33312}};
ListPointPlot3D[{lst1, lst2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.04]], 
                   Directive[Green, PointSize[0.02]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @lol - +1 on simultaneous answer...

Comment: @rasher, I accidentally/luckily hit `Submit` before loading the picture - it would have taken more than two seconds to load it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{{0.35, 5.9709, -0.494276}, {0.25, 
    6.4709, -0.794276}, {0.3, 6.2709, -0.564276}, {0.3, 
    5.6709, -0.594276}}, {{0.3, -3.41212, -1.20591}, {0.4, -3.21543, -1.12591}, 
    {0.4, -3.61472, -1.33312}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Blue, PointSize[0.02]}], 
   Directive[{Darker[Green], PointSize[0.01]}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be out of scope of your question but you can see how powerful is Mathematica.

```
 lst1 = {{0.35, 5.9709, -0.494276}, {0.25, 6.4709, -0.794276},
            {0.3,6.2709, -0.564276}, {0.3,5.6709, -0.594276}};
lst2 = {{0.3, -3.41212, -1.20591}, {0.4,-3.21543, -1.12591}, {0.4, -3.61472, -1.33312}};

Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[{lst1, lst2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[color1, PointSize[size1]], 
    Directive[color2, PointSize[size2]]}], {color1, 
  ColorSlider}, {color2, ColorSlider}, {size1, 0.01, 0.1}, {size2, 
  0.01, 0.1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I post this just for variety (using `Graphics3D`):

```
bb = {{0.35, 5.9709, -0.494276}, {0.25, 6.4709, -0.794276}, {0.3, 
    6.2709, -0.564276}, {0.3, 5.6709, -0.594276}};
lg = {{0.3, -3.41212, -1.20591}, {0.4, -3.21543, -1.12591}, {0.4, \
-3.61472, -1.33312}};
style = {{Blue, PointSize[0.04]}, {Green, PointSize[0.02]}};
Graphics3D[MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, Point@#2} &, {style, {bb, lg}}],
  Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 0.5, 1}]
```

[image]